# Need to get a MSSQL table to show 25 records at a time in PHP using PDO

Tags: php, html, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to get a MSSQL table to limit to 25 records to show up and then the rest show a number at the bottom that says 1 through what ever number it ends and be able to click on each number to show 100 records.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Completed Request Status</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../../css/table.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../javascript/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="main-wrap">


    <div class="main-content"> 


 <?php
    //conects to the database
    require_once("../../db_connect.php");

    //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Completed' Limit 100");
    $stmt->execute();

    ?>

    <?php //start of the while loop ?>
    <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>

 <table border="1" style="border: thin #000000; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; display: table;" class="style1">

    <tr> 
        <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Request#</strong></th>
        <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Status</strong></th>
        <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Comments</strong></th>
        <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Date Requested</strong></th>
        <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th style="width:10%;  background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Department</strong></th>
    <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
    <strong>VasLblDate</strong></th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php $id = $row['RequestNumber'];?>
    <?php echo  "<td> <a href='../../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>

        <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Comments']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['DATEREQUESTED']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['EmpName']; ?></strong></td>
    <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['VasLblDate']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width: 62px;"class="style3"><strong>Work Requested</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong># Of Cases Missing</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong># Of Stray Cases Found/To Move</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong># Of Cases To Consume</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>PO #</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>IS # 
        </strong> </th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Vendor Name 
        </strong> </th>


    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['Effortrequest']; ?></strong></td>
         <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Missing']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Located']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Dissassociated']; ?>
        </strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['PONumber']; ?></strong></td>
    <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['IBS']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Vendor']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width: 62px;"class="style3"><strong>Case 1</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Case 2</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Case 3</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style2"></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Description</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Comments</strong></th>
    <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Carrier</strong></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['CaseOne']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['CaseTwo']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['CaseThree']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['']; ?></strong></td>
       <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['ReqDescription']; ?></strong></td>
  <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['MoreComments']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Carrier']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>
<tr> 
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width: 62px;"class="style3"><strong>Trip</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>DC Remarks Update by</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>DC Remarks Updated</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong># Of Actual Cases Consumes</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>EE Performing Consume Cases</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3" class="style2">
        <strong>Store Number</strong></th>
    <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width:60px; height: 25px;" class="style3">
    <strong>Reason</strong></th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['Trip']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['RemarksBy']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['CompDT']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['CaseCount']; ?></strong></td>
         <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['WHODIS']; ?></strong></td>
     <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['StoreNumber']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Reason']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>


    <tr> 
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width: 62px;"class="style3"><strong>New IS#</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>New Carrier Shipment#</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Deleted Case#</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Notes</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3"><strong>Inbound User ID</strong></th>
        <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4;"class="style3" class="style2">
        <strong>Was Shipment</strong></th>
    <th style="background-color: #F4F4F4; width:60px; height: 25px;" class="style3">
    <strong>Verified BY</strong></th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['NewIS']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['NewCSN']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['DCN']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['MoreComments']; ?></strong></td>
         <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['AreaID']; ?></strong></td>
     <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Verified']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['VerifiedID']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>


    </table>
 <?php } //end of the while loop?>

    </div>

</div>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../../javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google "php pagination"

Comment: I check for it online only problem is I am using access db so I don't know it that will make a diffrence

Comment: I will have to go through tutorial thought it would be easy to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` function to limit your query to a subset. From the MySQL docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

All you need to do is determine your offset and your paging size:

```
$num_per_page = 25;
// Get this from the user (and default to 1 as the first page)
$page = (int)$_GET['page'] ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Completed' Limit :offset,:limit");
$stmt->execute(array(':offset' => int($num_per_page * ($page-1)), ':limit' => $num_per_page));
```

Comment: I will give this a try and see what I come up with

Comment: I am not understanding this to well

Comment: Can you explain what you are having problems with? You should be able to just replace the code under `require_once("../../db_connect.php");` with the code I've posted.

Comment: do I replace this 
    //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Completed' Limit 100");
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: when I add the code the table disaapears I will check error log see what it says

Comment: Let me know if you find something in the error logs and we can try debug it.

Comment: nothing showed up not sure if it has to do with limit because I am using access db not MySQL

Comment: Well lets try hard coded values: `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Completed' LIMIT 10,10"); $stmt->execute();`. Does using that give you the second set of 10 entries?

Comment: Sorry I think Limit statement only works for MySQL not access so I think I will mark your question correct because I am sure it will work with MySQL

Comment: $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Top 100 * FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Completed'"); This is whats working for me to select 100 records but still need to figure pagination I am using MSSQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69252/discussion-between-tom-and-veronica).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69269/discussion-between-veronica-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

use $_get (or $_post) to get the current page and do limit in your query
for example limit (($id-1)*25,($id-1)*25+25)
for $id=1 will show you 1,25